# In drinking hot, warm, room temperature, or cold water - is water temperature proven to be connected with any health benefit?

Tags: digestion, water, hydration

Is there scientific proof that the temperature of water (e.g., above or below room temperature) in our water consumption is connected with any health benefit? Auyrveda testimonials I've seen online seem to say that [usually they seem to discuss drinking hot water in the morning] is connected with helping digestion, but I'm wondering if any scientific / medical studies support that? Have read in [other threads](https://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/6915/why-is-cold-water-more-refreshing-than-warm-water) here (on the Biology exchange) that "the temperature of the ingested water will not affect the overall hydration of the body" which is helpful. Does this include that it does not affect things like bowel movement and digestive health?

(This question is regarding water only - not with lemon, not tea etc.)

Thanks.

Comment: Ayurveda is not science, so any claims based on it regarding health, biology, or any empyrical field should always be taken with a large portion of skepticism.

Comment: I know some martial arts instructors that say room temperature based on Ancient Chinese medicine.

Answer (score 1):

Asking about "any health benefit" is perhaps too broad to receive a complete answer.

However, several articles address the issue of water temperature and rehydration. Two studies have shown that when you are in a state of dehydration (in these studies, after physical activity), the optimal drinking-water temperature in terms of good hydration and lower sweating (which causes water loss as a cooling mechanism) was found to be 16°C.

To quote the conclusions of both studies:

"When dehydrated subjects drink water with different temperatures, there are different sweating responses together with different voluntary intakes. According to our results, consuming 16°C water, cool tap water, could be suggested in dehydration."

"For athletes dehydrated in hot environments, maximum voluntary drinking and best hydration state occurs with 16°C water.Provision of fluid needs and thermal needs could be balanced using 16°C water.Drinking 16°C water (nearly the temperature of cool tap water) could be recommended for exercise in the heat."

References:

[The effect of water temperature and voluntary drinking on the post rehydration sweating](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC3762624/)

[Water temperature, voluntary drinking and fluid balance in dehydrated taekwondo athletes](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/24149564)